# Was Gargoyle World Tour randomly done or is there any pattern?

Tags: analysis, gargoyles

In *Gargoyles*, after leaving from Avalon, Goliath, Elisa, Angela, and Bronx go through so many countries/locations before returning back to Avalon and then Manhattan.

But was there any pattern in this tour?

It is said that Avalon sent them where they were needed, that's why they were sent back to Avalon when they were needed there instead but is there any pattern in this tour or any symbolism?